# Running web application developed using .NET 4.5 on Windows Xp clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows

I'm aware of the fact that Microsoft have officially announced that .NET Framework does not support on Windows Xp. so no more hopes for developing for .NET 4.5 on Windows Xp.

Does it also mean that if I complied the WEB application on .NET 4.5, it will not load on client's browsers with Windows Xp running?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not what it means. Their browsers will read HTML, which is what is delivered to them from .NET websites.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. so browsers show what renders from the server and it doesn't need the relevant framework running on the OS. Please confirm.

Comment: Yes. Stackoverflow is based on .NET and it's working on my iPhone right now:). Plus I can guarantee my website has XP ppl running IE6 hitting it too... Who knows why tho.

Comment: @ecasper     But browser won't care where the html comes from. That's irrelevant to the client.

Comment: Web development is tricky enough trying to get things to work across all browsers. I shudder to think if we had to worry about back end framework compatibility with client system.

Comment: And side note, maybe you are thinking about winforms and writing exe programs. That's a different story.

Comment: No I'm specific to WEB applications, so I don't have to worry about exe programs. do I?