# Can iOS run websites written in C# only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ios, silverlight, web

I've read that to view websites written in ASP.NET and C#, the current device needs to support Silverlight. Does iOS devices support Silverlight? and if no can an iOS device even view websites where the functionality is only written in C#?

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Similar recent post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19074458/1810243

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device does not need to support Silverlight. ASP .NET renders HTML, which can be viewed by any device.

Silverlight is a separate kind of technology, that has nothing to do with HTML. If you make a Silverlight project, the device needs to support it. iOS does not support Silverlight, in the same way as it does not support Flash and other popular runtimes.